# Python: inconsistent handling of IF statement in loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I have a dataframe `df` containing conditions and values.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'COND':['X','X','X','Y','Y','Y'], 'VALUE':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})
```

Therefore `df` looks like:

```
  COND  VALUE
     X      1
     X      2
     X      3
     Y      1
     Y      2
     Y      3
```

I'm using a loop to subset `df` according to `COND`, and write separate text files containing values for each condition

```
conditions = {'X','Y'}
for condition in conditions:
    df2 = df[df['COND'].isin([condition])][['VALUE']]
    df2.to_csv(condition + '_values.txt', header=False, index=False)
```

The end results is two text files: X_vals.txt and Y_vals.txt, both of which contain `1 2 3`. Up until this point everything is working as expected.

I would like to further subset `df` for one condition only. For example, perhaps I want all values from condition Y, but ONLY values < 3 from condition X. In this scenario, X_vals.txt should contain `1 2` and Y_vals.txt should contain `1 2 3`. I tried implementing this with an IF statement:

```
conditions = {'X','Y'}
for condition in conditions:
    if condition == 'X':
        df = df[df['VALUE'] < 3]

    df2 = df[df['COND'].isin([condition])][['VALUE']]
    df2.to_csv(condition + '_values.txt', header=False, index=False)
```

Here is where the inconsistency occurs. The above code works fine (i.e. X_vals.txt contains `1 2`, and Y_vals.txt `1 2 3`, as intended), but when I use `if condition=='Y'` instead of `if condition=='X'`, it breaks, and both text files only contain `1 2`.

In other words, if I specify the first element of `conditions` in the IF statement then it works as intended, however if I specify the second element then it breaks and applies the < 3 subset to values from both conditions.

What is going on here and how can I resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: `df = df[df['VALUE'] < 3]` you changed initial dataframe in loop - that's your mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are encountering arises because you are overwriting `df` inside the loop.

```py
conditions = {'X','Y'}
for condition in conditions:
    if condition == 'X':
        df = df[df['VALUE'] < 3]  # <-- HERE'S YOUR ISSUE

    df2 = df[df['COND'].isin([condition])][['VALUE']]
    df2.to_csv(condition + '_values.txt', header=False, index=False)
```

What slightly surprised me is that when you are looping over the set `conditions` you get `condition = 'Y'` first, *then* `condition = 'X'`. But as a set is an *unordered collection* (i.e. it doesn't claim to have an inherent order of its elements), this ought not to be too disturbing: python is just reading out the elements in the most internally convenient way.

You could use `conditions = ['X', 'Y']` to loop over a list (an ordered collection) instead. Then it will do X first, then Y. However, if you do that you will get the same bug but in reverse (i.e. it works for `if condition == 'Y'` but not `if condition == 'X'`).

This is because after the loop runs once, `df` has been reassigned to the subset of the original `df` that only contains values less than three. That's why you get only the values 1 and 2 in both files if the `if condition` statement triggers on the **first pass through the loop**.

Now for the fix:

```py
conditions = ['X', 'Y']

for condition in conditions:

    csv_name = f"{condition}_values.txt"

    if condition == 'X':
        df_filter = f"VALUE < 3 & COND == '{condition}'"
    else:
        df_filter = f"COND == '{condition}'"

    df.query(df_filter).VALUE.to_csv(csv_name, header=False, index=False)
```

Here I've introduced the `DataFrame.query` method, which is typically more concise than trying to create a Boolean series to use as a mask as you were doing.

The f-string syntax only works on python 3.6+, if you're on a lower version then modify as appropriate (e.g. `df_filter = "COND == '{}'".format(condition)`)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Could you please clarify how to adapt for lower versions on each line using f-string?

Comment: That's what I meant by my example on the last line. There are multiple ways to format strings but one way is the string's `format` method. In each case just remove the `f` prefix and put `.format(condition=condition)` on the end of the string. Or, for brevity, `.format(condition)` and change `{condition}` to `{}` as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

We can write the condition to `dict` then use `map` filter the df before `groupby`

```
cond = {'X' : 2, 'Y' : 3}
subdf = df[df['VALUE']<df.COND.map(cond)]
for x, y in subdf.groupby('COND'):
    y.to_csv(x + '_values.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this workaround, however I'm really trying to understand what is wrong with the existing code. I'm working with a script that uses a more complicated version of what I described above, so I need to know what is going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'COND':['X','X','X','Y','Y','Y'], 'VALUE':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})

conditions = df.COND

for condition in conditions:
 print(condition)
 df2=df[df['COND'].isin([condition])][['VALUE']]
 df2.to_csv(condition + '_values.txt',header=False, index=False)


for condition in conditions:
 if condition=='X':
     df=df[df['VALUE'] < 3]

 df2=df[df['COND'].isin([condition])][['VALUE']]
 df2.to_csv(condition + '_values.txt',header=False, index=False)
```

You didn't specify the variable "Condition", so it gave you an error.
try doing :

conditions = df.COND

before the for loop

Comment: Woops - I had originally defined conditions as conditions={'X','Y'} (have edited to include this) BUT your answer revealed something new. Defining conditions with conditions={'X','Y'} causes the problem I described, however using conditions=df.COND  as you suggest causes the code to fail every time - that is, all of df is always subsetted, no matter which condition I use in the IF statement. Interesting...